# Records not showing results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, record

```
CREATE TABLE manager (
      mgrid        INT PRIMARY KEY,
      fname        VARCHAR2(50),
      city         VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

The above is the manager table.

& Below is the code I wrote to get records.

```
DECLARE
      TYPE mgr_info IS RECORD (
            mgrid   manager.mgrid%TYPE,
            fname  manager.fname%TYPE,
            city   manager.city%TYPE
      );
        mgr    mgr_info;
        id   manager.mgrid%TYPE;
        name  manager.fname%TYPE;
        mcity   manager.city%TYPE;
BEGIN
      SELECT
            mgrid,
            fname,
            city
      INTO mgr
      FROM
            manager
      WHERE
            city = 'Mumbai';

      id := mgr.mgrid;
      name := mgr.fname;
      mcity := mgr.city;
      dbms_output.put_line('Manager ID = '
                           || id
                           || ' || Manager Name = '
                           || name
                           || ' || City = '
                           || mcity);

EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('No Matching Record Found');
      WHEN too_many_rows THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('More than one matching Record Found');
END;
/
```

The issue is I am not able to get proper input even though I have a row that is a manager who lives in Mumbai City.

What is I am not doing that I am not able to get proper output.

[image: This is the output I am getting]

Below are the inputs for the table:

```
insert into manager values(101,'mohan','jaipur');
insert into manager values(102,'sohan','surat');
insert into manager values(103,'rohan', 'delhi');
insert into manager values(104,'jagmohan','mumbai');
```

Comment: Regardless what you claim, Oracle disagrees and says that there are no rows in `manager` table whose `city = 'Mumbai'`. Please, post contents of that table. Even better, post a few `insert into` statement(s)!

Comment: @Littlefoot Yeah surely. I am sorry I didn't provide at first. I will edit the question asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table has `Mumbai`, the select uses `mumbai`. The case is different. @Littlefoot was right to ask for the `INSERT` statements, we couldn't have helped without them.

If you want the `SELECT` to work, you need to fold both table and query to the same case:

```
WHERE lower(city) = lower('Mumbai')
```